# Martingale CLT conditional variance normalization condition

Tags: probability-theory, martingales, central-limit-theorem

[Helland (1982)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/4615860.pdf) (Theorem 2.5) gives the following conditions for a martingale central limit theorem.

Given a triangular martingale difference array $\{(\xi_{n,k}, \mathcal{F}_{n,k})\}$, if any of the following sets of conditions below is satisfied, then a martingale CLT holds:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n} \xi_{n,k} \xrightarrow{d} \mathcal{N}(0,1)$$

---

**Set 1**

1.a) $\sum_{k=1}^{n} E[\xi_{n,k}^2 I\{|\xi_{n,k}| > \epsilon \} | \mathcal{F}_{n,k-1}] \xrightarrow{p}  0\quad$ for all $\epsilon > 0$

**1.b)** $\sum_{k=1}^{n} Var[\xi_{n,k} | \mathcal{F}_{n,k-1}] \xrightarrow{p} 1$

---

**Set 2**

2.a) $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \xi_{n,k}^2 \xrightarrow{p} 1$

**2.b)** $E[\max_{1 \leq k \leq n} |\xi_{k,n}|] \to 0$

---

**Set 3**

3.a) $\max_{1 \leq k \leq n} |\xi_{k,n}| \xrightarrow{p} 0$

**3.b)** $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \xi_{n,k}^2 \xrightarrow{p} 1$

3.c) $\sum_{k=1}^{n} \left|E[\xi_{n,k}I\{|\xi_{n,k}| > 1\} | \mathcal{F}_{n,k-1}] \right| \to 0$

---

**Question: What kind of assumptions imply the conditional variance / quadratic variability conditions (1.b), (2.b) or (2.c)?**

For example, [Hall and Heyde (1980, p53)](http://www.stat.yale.edu/~mjk56/MartingaleLimitTheoryAndItsApplication.pdf) comment that martingale arrays are commonly constructed from ordinary martingale differences $\{ (X_{k}, \mathcal{F}_{k}) \}$ by

$$\xi_{n,k} := \frac{X_{k}}{\sqrt{\sum_{k} E[X_{k}^2]}}$$

In this case, e.g. condition 1.b implies that the sum of conditional variances increases at exactly the same rate as the unconditional sum:

$$\frac{\sum_{k} E[X_{k}^2| \mathcal{F}_{k-1}]}{\sum_{k} E[X_{k}^2]} \xrightarrow{p} 1$$

When is this sort of condition true?